# Extjs4 display tooltip for accordion item headers

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tooltip, accordion

Is there are any way to add tooltip for Extjs accordion item headers.I am using tree panel for accordion item.

My accordian panel

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    region: 'west',
    split: true,
    width: '20%',
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Accordian',
    iconCls: 'application-side-tree',
    layout: 'accordion',
    items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        id: 'tree-1',
        store: Store1,
        title: 'First item tree',
        rootVisible: false,
        layout: 'fit',
        draggable: false
    }),
        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        id: 'tree-2',
        store: Store2,
        title: 'Second item tree',
        rootVisible: false,
        layout: 'fit',
        draggable: false
    })
        ],
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QuickTips` for example:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: '80%',
    title: 'Accordian',
    layout: 'accordion',
    items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'First item tree',
            tooltip: 'tip 1',
            html: 'blah blah'
        }),
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Second item tree',
            tooltip: 'tip 2',
            html: 'blah blah'
        })
    ],
    height: 200
});

panel.items.each(function(p) {
    Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: p.header.id,
        html: p.tooltip
    });
});

Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/r4tt5/